# Finding parent or sibling browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jsp

Ok, this is a little broad but please, please don't ding me. I am grasping at straws here...

I have a third party web application. They have given us a "plugin" approach in which a button event can call a .jsp page. So through their application the user clicks on a button that calls this .jsp page that launches our browser page through a redirect (currently). We have full control of this jsp page.

The problem is we need to detect somehow when the third party web app closes so we can close.

We are open to all ideas. Worse case, if it helps, a jsp or asp.net page that spawns the third party web app.

This is being driven by HIPAA compliance.

Gina

Comment: why don't you just timeout the original page?

Comment: @epascarello That is worse case and may not meet compliance. If they close the main app and walk away. It could take 10 minutes or so for our window to timeout (anything else would be really annoying). This gives a chance for unscrupulous people to see confidential info.

Comment: So you can use window.opener and get a reference, but if they leave the domain, you would have to use post messaging and you can't close the parent page because it was not opened by you with window.open.

Comment: sounds like the easiest solution would be to get them to not open it in a new window? :)

Comment: Use an iframe overlay in existing page?

Comment: @epascarello create an answer for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a window is opened from another window (using Window.open or a
>   link with its target attribute set), it maintains a reference to that
>   first window as window.opener. If the current window has no opener,
>   this method returns NULL.
>   - [MDN - window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

You can check if window.opener is null then the main window is closed.

Comment: ok, this is the correct answer but looks like Epascarello came up with it first...

Comment: if (window.opener)... works but then how do I get more attributes from the parent window?

Comment: `var oWindow = window.opener` you have access to the window object of the parent. You can do all the operations as you do on regular window object. `oWindow.document` will give you document of the parent

Comment: I get a cross domain error even though both sites are on the same domain.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Fixed - brought both apps under same domain (same subdomain as well since different subdomains still cause cross domain issues).